# Why can't I set env vars in cmd. Unable to use azcopy to copy from S3

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I need to copy an 3S bucket to an Azure blob storage container. I'm trying to use azcopy. However it doesn't work because I cannot set the required AWS keys as env vars.

I have followed this guide: https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2019/06/migrate-aws-s3-buckets-to-azure-blob-storage/

I set the variables:

```
set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<my key>
set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<my secret>
```

I then use:

```
azcopy copy <my s3 bucket> <my blob container SAS> --recursive=true
```

It spits out this:

```
INFO: Scanning...

failed to perform copy command due to error: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment variables must be set before creating the S3 AccessKey credential
```

When I try azcopy env it shows nothing set for the aws key and redacted for the secret:

```
INFO: Name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
Current Value:
Description: The AWS access key ID for S3 source used in service to service copy.

INFO: Name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
Current Value: REDACTED
Description: The AWS secret access key for S3 source used in service to service copy.
```

Any help much appreciated as always!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use:

setx AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
setx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

Restarted terminal tried azcopy again and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was setting the `AZCOPY_CONCURRENT_FILES`
variable. Then I figured out you have to set the environment variables as you set them on **PowerShell** ( with **$ sign**) .

i.e `$env:AZCOPY_CONCURRENCY_VALUE = 256`

Have a try following code to set the access key

- `$env:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = <access_key>`
- `$env:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = <secret_key>`